# What happens if : char x = short y in c++

Tags: c++, types, char, short

Like the title says I have this code :

```
void Emulator::cpu16BitLoad(char& hi, char& lo)
{
    m_cyclesThisUpdate += 12;
    short n = readShort();
    m_programCounter += 2;
    lo = n;
    hi = n << 8;
}
```

I want to know if my variable 'lo' will contain the last 8 bits of n

Comment: run it and find out?

Comment: It's implementation-defined.  If you use `unsigned char`, you'll get consistent behaviour across all platforms.

Comment: `n` should be `unsigned short` or even better `uint16_t` and it should be `hi = n >> 8;` `hi` an `lo` should be `uint8_t`

Comment: @MarcB: That will give you the answer for one particular implementation. Unfortunately, it won't tell you whether it's portable.

Answer (score 2):

As per the Standard section **4.7 Integral conversions** [conv.integral]

> **1** A prvalue of an integer type can be converted to a prvalue of another integer
> type. A prvalue of an unscoped
> enumeration type can be converted to a prvalue of an integer type.
>
> **2** If the destination type is unsigned, the resulting value is the least
> unsigned integer congruent to the source integer (modulo 2n where n is
> the number of bits used to represent the unsigned type). [ *Note:* In a
> two’s complement representation, this conversion is conceptual and
> there is no change in the bit pattern (if there is no truncation).
> *—end note* ]
>
> **3** If the destination type is signed, the value is unchanged if it can be
> represented in the destination type (and
> bit-field width); otherwise, the value is implementation-defined.

So, given that the destination type is "char" it can actually be signed (usually) or unsigned. The compiler is only required to take the bottom eight bits in the latter case.

IE you should write this:

```
void load(unsigned char &lo)
{
    unsigned short val = /* get it somewhere */;
    lo = val;
}
```